# stretch out portion of x-axis on pandas dataframe plot (plotting uneven x-axis)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mfr = pd.Series([0.005466175615429347, 0.5, 0.9166666666666666,
                 0.7777777777777778, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0,
                 0.9565217391304348, 0.9047619047619048, np.nan,
                 np.nan, np.nan, 0.8235294117647058,
                 0.7272727272727273, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.5, 0.5,
                 0.5714285714285714, 0.8, 0.46153846153846156, 0.625,
                 0.3157894736842105, 0.6666666666666666, 0.046875,
                 0.10909090909090909, 0.16346153846153846,
                 0.043478260869565216, 0.023809523809523808,
                 0.012048192771084338, 0.007556675062972292,
                 0.0050858232676414495, 0.0, 0.0009668842156151801,
                 0.0005015045135406219, 0.0, 0.0002106002106002106], name='mfr')

score = pd.Series([3000, 2500, 2000, 1500, 1400, 1300, 1200, 1100,
                   1000, 900, 800, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300, 250, 200, 190, 180, 170,
                   160, 150, 140, 130, 120, 110, 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20,
                   10, 0], name='score')

df = pd.concat([score, mfr], axis=1)
```

As you can see the `score` values between 0 and 200 are have a spacing
of `10` while the spacing after that point varies. I want to be able
to plot this taking `score` on the `x-axis` and `mfr` on the `y`
axis. I want the plot to *stretch out* the `x-values` between 0 and
200 so that the plot isn't *squished* together as in my failed plot
(see below). I also want the `x-ticks` to be the exact values for
`score` column of the pandas dataframe (ranging from 0 to 3000)

Here is what I have tried (wishful code commented out):

```py
a = np.arange(0, 3000, 200)

ax = df.interpolate().plot(x='score', y='mfr', figsize=(15, 4))

# ax.xaxis.set_ticks(df['score'])
# ax.xaxis.set_ticks(a)
# ax.set_xscale('symlog')
# ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(df.score)
```

[image]
My stackoverflow searches sent me [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39540730/6431877)

Trying to emulate the solution suggested on there doesn't help.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I'd add `plt.xscale('log')`.

Comment: Use `log` scale for x-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the x-axis could be interpreted as categorical, so showing one tick per entry in the score column:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# df = ...
df['ind'] = df.index
ax = df.interpolate().plot(x='ind', y='mfr', figsize=(12, 4), rot=25)
ax.set_xticks(df.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['score'])
ax.set_xlabel('score')
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True) # optionally leave out the padding for the x-axis
ax.invert_xaxis() # optionally invert the x-axis (the dataframe goes from high to low score)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]