# matplotlib Y-axis spacing adjustment

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I use python to make a graph for the response time, and the Y-axis is the time/sec, I used two pieces of data, but there is a gap between the two pieces of data.

This is my plot Y-axis, like the picture "L" ,and I want it evenly dispersed like the "R", each interval has the same length ,how can I use matplotlib to do this?

[image]

```py
plt.yticks([0, 2500, 5000, 7500, 10000, 30000, 50000, 60000])
```

I use yticks to get the picture "L".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make xticks evenly spaced despite their value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540730/how-to-make-xticks-evenly-spaced-despite-their-value)